# Remove OCG layers from PDF with Python

Tags: python, pdf, ocg

Is there a way to delete an OCG layer from a PDF within Python?

I normally work with pymupdf but couldn't the functionality there. Is there any other library with this functionality?

Comment: What does ocg stand for?

Comment: @MartinThoma OCG = Optional Content Group. You can put for example highlights into an OCG layer in a PDF and the PDF viewer will then have the option to show the layer or not.

Comment: @Kait have you found any solution? I can see `Document.delete_page()` but nothing for the ocg

Answer (score 0):

disclaimer: I am the author of `borb` the library mentioned in this answer.

`borb` will turn any input PDF into a JSON-like data structure. If you know what to delete in the content-tree, you can simply remove that item from the dictionary as you would in a normal dictionary object.

Reading the `Document` is easy:

```py
with open("input.pdf", "rb") as in_file_handle:
    document = PDF.loads(in_file_handle)
```

You need `document["XRef"]["Trailer"]["Root"]["OCGs"]` which will be a `List` of layers. Remove whatever element(s) you want.

If you then store the PDF, the layer will be gone.

```py
with open("output.pdf", "wb") as out_file_handle:
    PDF.dumps(out_file_handle, document)
```

Comment: I just tried `borb`, I am wondering if borb deals with layers (OCG). `document["XRef"]["Trailer"]["Root"]` shows nothing about `layer`. Adding `["OCGs"]` said `KeyError: 'OCGs'`.